# Compiler didn't fire an error when creating an object from a Protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Here is the code example from the resource I've reading

```
protocol Vehicle {
    var weight: Int { get }
    var name: String { get set }
}

protocol WheeledVehicle: Vehicle {
    var numberOfWheels: Int { get }
    var wheelSize: Double { get set }
}


class Bike: WheeledVehicle{
    var weight: Int = 30
    var name: String = "kukulus"
    var numberOfWheels: Int = 2
    var wheelSize: Double = 16.2}

var bike: Bike = Bike()

bike.numberOfWheels = 16

var wheeledBike: WheeledVehicle = bike // *** There will be an error, in fact not.
```

For the last line (marked with ***)

**Question 1** The book I read claimed that here will be an error fired by the compiler that "***Cannot assign to numberOfWheels!***", however, it's not. Is the book wrong?

**Question 2**  `var wheeledBike: WheeledVehicle = bike` where `WheeledVehicle` is a protocol, isn't it like an abstract class that protocol cannot instantiate an object? if so, why didn't the compiler give me an error warning?

Update:
If adds the following code, there will be an error notice

```
wheeledBike.numberOfWheels = 4
```

The book is not wrong, the above line will introduce an error, not the line marked with ***

Thanks a lot for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code you are creating a `Bike` object, which has `var numberOfWheels` property, `var` means you can change it and thats why you are able to change the value of `numberOfWheels`.

```
var bike: Bike = Bike()
bike.numberOfWheels = 16
```

---

The following line works because `Bike` class conforms to protocol `WheeledVehicle`, thus `bike` can be casted as `wheeledBike`. You are NOT creating a new object, but you are just assigning it to a new variable.

```
var wheeledBike: WheeledVehicle = bike
```

---

If you tried following code, it would fail, because `wheeledBike` is type of `WheeledVehicle` which has `var numberOfWheels: Int { **get** }`, here **get** means that by protocol, you are only able to retrieve this value, but you are **NOT** allowed to set/change it.

```
wheeledBike.numberOfWheels = 16
```

Comment: **wheeledBike** is type of **WheeledVehicle**, so **wheeledBike.wheelSize = 21** will not fail. because it has { set }. And bike is a type of **Bike**. Because the type/class Bike set the **numberOfWheels** as variable, so if I type **bike.numberOfWheels = 6** it will also work. Am I in the right way?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what happens.

Comment: @orges Thanks a lot :)